# Why flask background thread get wrong database information?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

In order to push real time database info to client, I use flask-socketio in server side by using websocket to push all real-time database info to client.

There is a snippet of my view file:

```
from ..models import Host
from flask_socketio import emit, disconnect
from threading import Thread
thread = None

def background_thread(app=None):
    """
   send host status information to client
    """
    with app.app_context():
        while True:
            # update host info interval
            socketio.sleep(app.config['HOST_UPDATE_INTERVAL'])
            # socketio.sleep(5)
            all_hosts = dict([(host.id, host.status) for host in Host.query.all()])
            socketio.emit('update_host', all_hosts, namespace='/hostinfo')


@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    all_hosts = Host.query.all()
    return render_template('dashboard.html', hosts=all_hosts, async_mode=socketio.async_mode)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/hostinfo')
def on_connect():
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        app = current_app._get_current_object()
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=background_thread, app=app)
    emit('my_response', {'data': 'conncted'})

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/hostinfo')
def on_disconnect():
    print 'Client disconnected...', request.sid


@socketio.on('my_ping', namespace="/hostinfo")
def ping_pong():
    emit('my_pong')
```

However, when I update my database `Host table`, `Host.query.all()` still get old information. I don't know why?

Comment: First of all, I think the problem is `current_app`, I think `current_app` is just like a snapshot, so push this context, thread will get an imutable database table. However, I add or delete rows from the Host table, then, thread will query Host table with these rows deleted or added. However, I update the row, thread still get old row information, this is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot to @miguelgrinberg. Because background thread just use an old session, so each iteration, the thread just get the cached session. So add `db.session.remove()` at the end of `while True` loop, each iteration will start a clean session.